# Modern way to git clone a repository while building a Docker image to the GitLab Container Registry

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, git-clone

There seem to be much information around about this, but I cannot find a well described use-case with a modern approach (that is, without leaving traces or exposing credentials in the process).

Let's assume I am working from within GitLab group.
Inside such a group there are 2 repositories, A and B.

I'd like to build a docker image to the GitLab Container Registry of project B (or even the one of the highest-level group itself).

Project B needs project A, which is only available from its repository, so currently my `Dockerfile` looks something like this,

```
# Set the base image
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Install git
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y git

# Clone project
RUN GITLAB_GROUP=group_name git clone git@gitlab.com:$GITLAB_GROUP/A.git # for SSH
RUN GITLAB_GROUP=group_name git clone https://gitlab.com/$GITLAB_GROUP/A.git # for HTTP

[...]
```

(This of course cannot work as it is since there are no access permissions from within the Dockerfile.)

While the `.gitlab-ci.yml` would be at least something like the following,

```
build image:
  image: docker:20.10.17
  services:
    - docker:20.10.17-dind
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
  script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER $CI_REGISTRY --password-stdin
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to use [gitsubmodules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html) and then set the `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY`

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
```

That way the runner pulls the repository for you.